# How to conduct Hibernate Search within Lucene Index?

Tags: java, hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a `Double` field `price` in my entity class with annotation `@Field`. Now I need a query which will be used to retrieve product based on the price range provided by the user.

I am new to this `QueryBuilder` things in hibernate search and I couldn't find out the exact answer I am looking for. I am using hibernate search with Lucene Index. This question may be a duplicate one but actually I don't know where to begin and how. I appreciate any sort of help about this!

Comment: programming is not about copying ready stuff, if you dont know where to start, start at the beginning.... get a hibernate tutorial, and go through it, precise questions will arise automatically, solutions shortly later. Question flagged to close so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Query query = queryBuilder
    .range()
    .onField("myField")
    .from(x).to(y).excludeLimit()
    .createQuery();
```

See [the docs, Chapter 5](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html) (Section 5.1.2.5, in particular, though you likely should read the rest of it as well).